# Trying to figure out how this could leak memory

Tags: go, memory-leaks, channel, goroutine

We're using a background worker which is a goroutine that simply selects on a work channel and a context's done channel in a loop, processing any work in a queue (completely empties the queue and processes whatever accumulated there before returning to waiting on either of those channels to signal).

The Queue is a simple slice with a lock - external actor hands off a work-item that enqueued within the lock.

Then the work channel is signaled, which wakes the worker goroutine to grab the lock, then the entire contents of that slice is grabbed and processed one at a time, until it then returns to the select to sleep until a new item is added to the queue.

Ostensibly this works, but we've noticed that memory appears to become tied up in this process -- basically, anything that is handed to the queue never seems to be freed later.  The GC simply holds it forever, and eventually the app OOMs.

What is currently eluding us is how this memory isn't being freed by the GC.

The relevant bits are:

```
func (q *workQueue) enqueue(e any) {

    // put one item on end of current list
    q.lock.Lock()
    q.items = append(q.items, e)
    q.lock.Unlock()

    // attempt to allow the bg thread to run, but don't block if it is already running
    // this will also allow it to start a new loop if it is currently in a run-cycle because we have a buffer of 1 slot in our chan
    select {
    case q.run <- true:
    default:
    }
}
```

and

```
func (q *workQueue) dequeue() (items []any) {

    // unlink our current queue and return that to our caller
    q.lock.Lock()
    items = q.items
    q.items = nil
    q.lock.Unlock()

    return
}
```

and

```
func (wc *Sender) run(ctx context.Context) {

    // loop ends when the channel is closed
    for {

        // wait on next control event (context cancelled or run signaled)
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return // context was cancelled - terminate
        case _, ok := <-wc.WorkQueue.run:
            if !ok {
                return // run channel was closed - terminate
            }
        }

        // grab the current queue (we'll attempt to process every item once)
        items := wc.WorkQueue.dequeue()

        // attempt to drain the current queue
        for _, wi := range items {

            // process this item
            wc.process(ctx, wi)

            // abort if the context has been cancelled
            err := ctx.Err()
            if err != nil {
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully this is pretty straightforward for others reading it.

You can see in the above that the act of dequeuing the work should result in the only reference to the underlying data being being discarded once the for loop cycles back to repeat.

```
    items := wc.WorkQueue.dequeue()
```

that literally nils out the queue's ref to items, gives us the only reference, and when we loop, items should be re-initialized to nil itself (discarding that reference, leaving all items without any remaining root references and hence eligible for GC.

But what we actually see - with multiple versions of Go (1.20.x), is that the memory footprint grows forever, even if we force the GC to be more aggressive by using GOMEMLIMIT, and pprof shows that it is the objects being handed to that work queue -- where they're allocated - that is what is holding all of that ram hostage.

Ideas / thoughts for what might be causing this issue?

do I need to explicitly drop `items = nil` at the end of that for loop just to be sure to clear any refs to the work items?

This loop is triggered quite often, and even if items is holding the last dequeue() worth of stuff while awaiting ctx.Done() or wc.WorkQueue.run channels to signal - that wouldn't cause it accumulate forever - only to hold the previous loop's data longer than it should, so this seems like a bogus line of reasoning.

Help?

Comment: If `dequeue` is getting called, then there will be nothing in `q.items` to hold the memory. Are you certain you are not leaving running goroutines? (and I have to acknowledge the elephant, why are you not using a channel for the queue itself, which gives you automatic synchronization, back pressure, etc?)

Comment: It is unlikely that the code you showed here is the source of the leak. Maybe `wc.process` is keeping the objects alive, or some other code related to the queued objects?

Comment: "only to hold the previous loop's data longer than it should, so this seems like a bogus line of reasoning" does it? Loop 1 it has 1 item, while that's being processed 2  are queued. Next iteration it processes 2, which takes longer than 1, so while that's going 4 are queued. Then while those are being processed, 8 are queued, and so on. Reset each time, yet continuously growing. It depends on what the utilization and queue pressure pattern looks like in practice.

Comment: I agree with JimB, that this is just a more complicated way of achieving what a `chan []any` could accomplish more simply, and with Burak that - as unnecessary as it is - there doesn't appear to be anything in this extra complication that would cause a memory leak.  i.e. the problem likely lies in the `wc.process()` implementation.

Comment: @Adrian That's an excellent point.  If creating the tasks continuously outpaces processing them, then they would constantly grow.  I'll think more about this, but my immediate thought is that if this was the issue, then the process should go back to normal mem levels once generating tasks stops.  We have tested this - it never returns to normal levels, ever.  It will give up some of its ram, and it grows more slowly using `GOMEMLIMIT` to force it to run the GC more often, but ultimately, that ram is never reclaimed, even at total idle.

Comment: The problem I have with "just use a channel" is that a channel, unless buffered, is synchronous between threads.  `A` puts a value on the channel and is blocked until `B` pulls it to process it - and then you have to know a priori - what depth?  Getting that wrong is a whole host of problems.  So using a single, buffered channel, as a semaphore, simply works better.  If I spun up more worker goroutines, then I could increase throughput and handle more requests/s, but eventually I'd still backup the producer threads waiting for the backlog to clear, synchronously.

Comment: Those are both interesting ideas... and I should probably go add some metrics to see how backed up that worker becomes.  How long is the queue on avg / max.  Very interesting...

Comment: Oh, and to give you insight into my expectation: that this worker is much faster than the producers.  So, typically, I expect 1 item on each run, and for it to be completed well before the producers have another.  But... maybe this is the source of failure?  My intuition here is simply completely wrong?  * If this is the case, again, I would expect mem to finally resolve after producers all go idle, which never happens :/ *
I did design it to handle unusual temporary delays in processing the background items - such as a temporary network failure or busy downstream server...

Comment: @Mordachai that depends on how you are measuring memory usage to determine if it's been freed. OS memory statistics will only show usage dropping after the OS *reclaims* memory; it does not tell you if the process has *freed* memory. All the GC can do is say "OS, you can have this RAM back", it can't control when the OS actually takes it back.

Comment: @Mordachai, channels are used for queue-like pipelines similar to this all the time, there is no special a-priori knowledge required, just reasonable architecture. Typically you would have a buffer (which you do need to choose before allocating) but that gives you a known limit where things will back up, which you can detect with builtins like `select` (this is the concept of back-pressure in a messaging system). Whereas now you have an unbounded queue which never will indicate a problem until you run out of resources.

Comment: To pedantically clarify @Adrian's comment a bit, the GC never frees memory, the garbage collector's sole purpose is to _reuse_ memory. There is a memory scavenger process that runs occasionally, which will offer memory back to the OS if it has been completely unused for long enough, but any occasional spike in memory usage will prevent that from happening because re-allocating is much more expensive than reusing.

Comment: I appreciate all the feedback!  Regarding the point that Go doesn't control when the OS actually reclaims the available ram - my understanding is that Go went back to using MADV_DONTNEED (as of 1.16) and not MADV_FREE which then is "seen" correctly by things like HTOP (which is what we're using to measure memory use).  So we should see everything that the GC marks as MADV_DONTNEED in HTOP pretty much instantly, once it runs.  Or the memory scavenger process if that's (correctly) what marks pages as MADV_DONTNEED...

Comment: @JimB I do appreciate your point about back-pressure.  This system can build up catastrophically since there are no limits on that queue size.  I'm not really wanting to put back pressure on the producers, but maybe having a relief valve of writing the queue out to disk (db e.g.) as a way to push off overwhelming work to wait out a more serious network issue might be sensible.

Comment: Update: So I think y'all are right that this is just a case of being backed up so badly that we OOM, rather than a memory leak, it's memory overload.  In our test scenario, we're simply out-producing the consumer by a mile, and that can lead to OOM.  Will scale up the background workers and look at overflowing to DB rather than exhausing ram.  Thanks!